# How to make @bind:event="oninput" work together with @onkeypress:preventDefault?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to let my users either

- type numeral characters in the input box
- or press +/- key.

The following is my attempt. Unfortunately, users can only press +/- (as well as up/down arrow), typing numeral characters is not possible.

How to solve this issue?

```
<p>Counter: @counter</p>


<input type="number" 
       @bind="counter"  
       @bind:event="oninput"
       @onkeypress="OnKeyPress"
       @onkeypress:preventDefault="true"
       />
@code {
    private int counter;
    private void OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "+")
            counter++;
        else if (e.Key == "-")
            counter--;
    }
}
```

## Edit

Another attempt that does not work as well.

```
<p>Counter: @counter</p>


<input type="number" 
       value="@counter"  
       @oninput="@(e=>counter=int.Parse(e.Value.ToString()))"
       @onkeypress="OnKeyPress"
       @onkeypress:preventDefault="true"
       />
@code {
    private int counter;
    private void OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "+")
            counter++;
        else if (e.Key == "-")
            counter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the solution: Just append `counter = int.Parse($"{counter}{e.Key}");` at the end of `OnKeyPress`. I will delete this question shortly.

Comment: No don't delete it. It's important question and should be left for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions

    <input type="number"
           @bind="counter"
           @bind:event="oninput"
           @onkeypress="OnKeyPress"
           @onkeypress:preventDefault="true" />
    @code {
        private int counter;
        private void OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == "+")
                counter++;
            else if (e.Key == "-")
                counter--;

            if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Key, "[0-9]"))
            {
                counter = int.Parse( e.Key );
            }
        }
    }
```